# Java wait/notify not call in thread

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton, synchronized

I have a problem when scheduling two threads (`ReadData` and `WriteData`). It seems that I can't notify after wait. 
Here is my class which I define and call:

Buffer: The buffer I use to read / write data. I synch this class.

```java
public class Buffer {
    // Size of buffer we use to store data
    public static final int SIZE = 10;

    // Data of buffer.
    private int[] values;

    // Count of element in data.
    private int count;

    // Instance of buffer, for singleton pattern 
    private static Buffer instance = null;

    // A signal show data in use (busy) or not
    private static Object mutex = new Object();

    // Constructor of buffer
    private Buffer(){
        values = new int[SIZE];
        count = 0;
    }

    // Get instance of buffer.
        public static  Buffer getInstance(){
            if(instance == null){
                synchronized (mutex) {
                    if(instance == null) instance = new Buffer();
                }           
            }
            return instance;
        }


        public void addValue(int value){
            synchronized (mutex) {
                if(count >= SIZE) return;

                values[count++] = value;
            }
        }

        // Return current data and then reset buffer.
        public int[] getValues(){
            synchronized (mutex) {
                if(count == 0) return null;

                int[] values = new int[count];
                System.arraycopy(this.values, 0, values, 0, count);
                count = 0;
                return values;
            }
        }

        public int getCount(){
            synchronized (mutex) {
                return count;
            }
        }
}
```

ReadData: This class I use to store data into the buffer.

```java
import java.util.Random;

public class ReadData implements Runnable {
    Buffer buffer = Buffer.getInstance();

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        Random random = new Random();
        while(true){
            if(buffer.getCount() >= Buffer.SIZE){
                try {
                    System.out.println("Read: is waiting. . .");
                    mState.readIsWaiting();
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Read: storing data");
                buffer.addValue(random.nextInt(Buffer.SIZE) + 1);
            }
        }

    }

    public interface ReadState{
        void readIsWaiting();
    }

    private ReadState mState;

    public void setReadState(ReadState state){
        mState = state;
    }

    public synchronized void makeNotify() {
        notifyAll();        
    }

}
```

WriteData: This class I use to get data from the buffer

```java
 public class WriteData implements Runnable {
        Buffer buffer = Buffer.getInstance();

        @Override
        public synchronized void run() {
            while(true){
                if(buffer.getCount() == 0){
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Write: is waiting. . .");
                        mState.writeIsWaiting();
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    int[] getdata = buffer.getValues();
                    System.out.println("first data: " + getdata[0]);
                }
            }

        }

        public interface WriteState{
            void writeIsWaiting();
        }

        private WriteState mState;

        public void setWriteState(WriteState state){
            mState = state;
        }

        public synchronized void makeNotify() {
            notifyAll();        
        }
    }
```

MyThread: The thread I use to start read/write

```java
package main;

import testing.ReadData;
import testing.WriteData;


public class MyThread implements ReadData.ReadState, WriteData.WriteState  {
    private ReadData read;
    private WriteData write;

    public void start(){
        read = new ReadData();
        write = new WriteData();
        read.setReadState(this);
        write.setWriteState(this);
        new Thread(read).start();
        new Thread(write).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeIsWaiting() {
        read.makeNotify();

    }

    @Override
    public void readIsWaiting() {
        write.makeNotify();

    }

}
```

That's it. Sometimes it works, many times it stops and waits.
How do I solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Probably unrelated to your problem but your `Buffer#getInstance()` method is not entirely thread safe. See [The "Double-Checked Locking is Broken" Declaration](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html) (make `instance` `volatile` to fix it)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it still has same issue!

Answer (score 0):

I think you've reversed the ReadData implementation with the WriteData. In the code shown, the ReadData thread will block if the buffer is full:

```
@Override
public synchronized void run() {
    Random random = new Random();
    while(true){
        if(buffer.getCount() >= Buffer.SIZE){
            try {
                System.out.println("Read: is waiting. . .");
                mState.readIsWaiting();
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Read: storing data");
            buffer.addValue(random.nextInt(Buffer.SIZE) + 1);
        }
    }

}
```

What you really need is:

```
@Override
public synchronized void run() {
    Random random = new Random();
    while(true){
        if(buffer.getCount() == 0){
            try {
                System.out.println("Read: is waiting. . .");
                mState.readIsWaiting();
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Read: storing data");
            buffer.addValue(random.nextInt(Buffer.SIZE) + 1);
        }
    }

}
```

Similarly, in the WriteData implementation, you should block if the buffer is full. This will happen if the reader hasn't had a chance to take the elements from the buffer. This should work for the WriteData code:

```
    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        while(true){
            if(buffer.getCount() >= Buffer.SIZE){
                try {
                    System.out.println("Write: is waiting. . .");
                    mState.writeIsWaiting();
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                int[] getdata = buffer.getValues();
                System.out.println("first data: " + getdata[0]);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I think that's not problem. you just swap read <-> write. the problem i think is scheduling. cause sometime it work, sometime not.

Comment: So according to you, it's okay for the reader to block if the buffer is full and it's okay for the writer to block if the buffer is empty?

Comment: you probably don't understand I mean. WriteData: I want get data from buffer and store somewhere (not just console, data not just array int), ReadData: I want read data from anysource and store to buffer. Buffer is (temporary) limit data.